# debugger not working node js with chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node js.
Created simple js file with debugger but it's not working with chrome.

Any help, guidance will be appreciated.

Here is what I have tried.

JS file,

```
➜ cat sample.js
console.log('before debugger')
debugger
console.log('after debugger')
```

Debugging process,

```
➜ node inspect sample.js
< Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/61b7c6a3-7bde-4b29-b16e-e7079d511b39
< For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
< Debugger attached.
Break on start in sample.js:1
> 1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { console.log('before debugger')
  2 debugger
  3 console.log('after debugger')
debug>
```

chrome://inspect/#devices

[image]

When I click inspect nothing happens,

[image]

Node version:

```
➜  node -v
v8.16.0
```

Comment: Are you using VS Code?

Comment: @palaѕн yes I'm using VS code.

Comment: Check this out then: [The Easiest Way to Debug Node.js — with VS Code](https://itnext.io/the-absolute-easiest-way-to-debug-node-js-with-vscode-2e02ef5b1bad)

Comment: test this commnad: node --inspect-brk=127.0.0.1:9229  index.js maybe work for you